# how to align centered text to the right in css?

Tags: css, text

I have a hero image and I want the text in it to be like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTbvR.jpg)

but all I can do is put the text in center (while it's shifted to center): [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QejwQ.jpg), or put in the right side (shifted to the right).

how do I combine?
Hope I'm understood.

Comment: You can do this in various ways.
1. you can create a div and give the position as absolute and some z-index to stack over the image and then you can play with right-left values in CSS.
2. You can use margin-left or right with dave div content.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content{
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  color: crimson;
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300">
  
  <div class="content">
    Woof!
  </div>
</div>
```

**Hope this help!**

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use flexbox and a background image to avoid using absolute:

```css
.img-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}
.img-container h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.img-container p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
    <p>A Subtitle</p>
  </div>
</div>
```